# Combining Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 for classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, sentinel-1

I have Sentinel-1 data with VV and VH bands at a 10-meter resolution, while my Sentinel-2 data consists of 10 bands with a mix of 10-meter and 20-meter resolutions. I intend to utilize both Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 bands for a random forest classification in Google Earth Engine (GEE). Should I reproject the Sentinel-2 data to ensure that all bands have a consistent 10-meter resolution, thereby potentially enhancing the classification accuracy? Additionally, I welcome any other suggestions you may have for improving the classification when integrating Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 data. My script is below:

```
 var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
.filterDate(ee.Date('2022-08-11'), ee.Date(2022-08-15))
.filterBounds(AOI)

var sentinel1_mean=sentinel1.median()

var sentinel2= (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
      .filterBounds(forest)
      .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '60HVC')
      .filterDate('2022-08-01', '2022-08-30'))
var sentinel2_mean= sentinel2.median()

// Reproject Sentinel-2 bands to 10m resolution
var s2_bands_reprojected = sentinel2_mean.map(function(image) {
  return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
    crs: sentinel1_mean.projection(), // Match the projection of Sentinel-1 bands
    scale: 10 // Set the desired resolution to 10 meters
  });
});

// Combine Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 bands into one image
var combined_image = sentinel1_mean.addBands(s2_bands_reprojected);
```